# jquery camera / aperture closing animation effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, photo, effect

does an animation in jquery / JQM for div elements exists, like the photo animation on the iphone (the closing aperture effect) ?

I want a visual feedback for a scanned barcode on a mobile device, something simpler would be ok too.

Found only slideshow plugins :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tutorial**

http://tutorialzine.com/2011/03/photography-portfolio-shutter-effect/

**Demo**

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/03/photography-portfolio-shutter-effect/

There may be others found by doing a search for `jQuery shutter`.